# Connection Timeout When Sending HTTP Request in Java

Tags: java, http, request

I'm using this simple code below to send an http request:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
 }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I've got always the same error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

My OS: Windows 7.
I can't find where is the problem. 
I've no internet connection problem.
I've already tried by getting off my firewall but It does not solve the problem. 
I think it's not a network problem because I've a similar c# code that works.

Comment: do you have proxy configuration for internet ?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me locally

Comment: This works on my machine so it means there is some problem with your connectivity. The code itself seems OK.

Comment: This code also executes fine locally for me. Likely Java is being blocked by Windows; or some other environment issue is at fault here.

Comment: No I don't have any proxy configuration and my connectivity seems to work because I can access the web. Where can I see if Java is being blocked by Windows?

Comment: @MaxDy Check firewall setting

Comment: I checked th Firewall Settings and both Eclispe and Java(TM) Platform Binary are allowed to communicate with the internet. It makes me crazy!

Comment: @MaxDy Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623188/what-is-the-underlying-issue-with-sporadic-connectivity-issues-using-sun-net-www)? Since you accepted an answer, tehBug thought might have insight into his problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with your firewall setting.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem was like [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623188/what-is-the-underlying-issue-with-sporadic-connectivity-issues-using-sun-net-www), the issue may be a network security setup on the other end (wherever you're trying to talk to), not your own firewall.